# deep sleep and suspend not working

Tags: 13.10

I am using ubuntu 13.10 on my dell inspiron 15- 3521 (non touch). The problem is deep sleep even suspend initially it works that is laptop enters deep sleep and even suspend initialy works but then waking up the screen i get a blackscreen which stays infinitely untill i long press power button and switch it off and then switch it on using same button. Can someone please help me? I would really appreciate it

Comment: I've had the same problem with my laptop and it got fixed when I installed the proprietary driver of my GPU (nVidia). Search for additional proprietary drivers for your machine in the Synaptic package manager and install a tested one. Hope that helps.